# Merging data tables in r with multiple conditions

Tags: r

I have two rather large datasets. One had 2.8 million observations and 43 variables, the other 66000 observations with 170 variables.

I want to merge them based on condition 1 (same company) and condition 2 (same year) and solely keep the matched observations. The final amount of observations is not important, all variables should be kept.

I think the problem might be that data 1 has multiple observations per year and data2 does not. However, every observation should get the value from data2 for that year.

`data3<-inner_join(data1, data2, by=c("company", "year"))` ->this code gives the vector memory exhaused code. I've upped the memory R uses tot 14GB and it changes nothing.

Comment: Based on your question, I think you're going to want to use `left_join`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `data.table` for this. Something like:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data1)
setDT(data2)
data3 <- data1[data2, on=.(company, year), nomatch=FALSE]
```

Comment: It worked after adding allow.cartesian=TRUE, thanks a lot!